# Adding multiple values (List) with single key in map

Tags: java, collections, dictionary, multimap

I have a method which search my db and get all the values from bar table. Take the returned rows and convert into bar objects and create stock object from bar. Bar is a subclass of stock.

```
public Map<Stock, List<Bar>> findBars() throws Exception {
        BarConverter barConverter = new BarConverter();
        List<Bar> bars = new ArrayList<Bar>();
        Map<Stock, List<Bar>> map = new HashMap<Stock, List<Bar>>();

        // get rows from db
        List<Map<String, Object>> rows = dbClient.get(tableName, null, null, "id");
        for (Map<String, Object> row : rows) {
            // get bar object from row
            Bar bar = barConverter.setData(row, market);
            bars.add(bar);

            // set stock and map containing stock & bar
            Stock stock = new Stock(bar.getTicker(), market, bar.getExchange());
            map.put(stock, bars);
        }
        // return map
        return map;
    }
```

Currently the above method give output like

```
{AAPL-US-NASDAQ=[AAPL,NASDAQ,2014-04-25,564.53,571.99,563.96,571.94,13000000,8.6174E8], GOOG-US-NASDAQ=[GOOG,NASDAQ,2014-04-25,1564.53,1581.99,263.96,371.94,13000000,1.6174E8], AAPL-US-NASDAQ=[AAPL,NASDAQ,2014-04-25,222.53,321.99,3121.96,571.94,13000000,8.6164E8] }
```

As you can see in the above output first their is Apple stock with its bar values, then google stock with its bar value and again apple stock with the some different bar values. How can group those two Apple bars with a single key. i.e. `Map<Stock, List<Bar>>`.

**Expected Output**

```
{AAPL-US-NASDAQ=[{AAPL,NASDAQ,2014-04-25,564.53,571.99,563.96,571.94,13000000,8.6174E8}, {AAPL,NASDAQ,2014-04-25,222.53,321.99,3121.96,571.94,13000000,8.6164E8}], GOOG-US-NASDAQ=[GOOG,NASDAQ,2014-04-25,1564.53,1581.99,263.96,371.94,13000000,1.6174E8]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a [multimap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimap). There is no standard multimap in Java.

A solution is described in Oracle's [Map tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html) and uses a Map whose values are Lists.

The alternative is to use a Multimap provided by another project. [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/) and [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) are two popular projects that provide Multimaps.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use a TreeMap wich is a sorted Map. 
(sorted by the natural order of the elements), it lets you define a custom sort order (via a Comparable or Comparator), The collection's key (the Stock object) must also implement the comparable interface.

Answer (score 0):

The technical solution is to use some kind of "advanced" Map, as described in the other answers.

I would argue that when you end up with complex maps for such simple cases, chances are that you're trying to run away from creating a simple object. This will probably lead you to some weird stuff when you need to aggregate another piece of data.

By creating a new class, it also allows you to improve readability later on, for example if you need to sum all `Bar`s for a given `Stock` :

```
/**
 * The simple way
 */
public class StockWithBarComposite {

   private Stock stock;

   private List<Bar> bars;

   /**
    * Some complex operation you can easily document here
    *
    * @return BigDecimal
    */
   public BigDecimal barSum() {
       // Loop, sum, whatever
   }

}
```